# After installing 12.04, mouse no longer works; then "Header: ??? ??? Body text: ??????" error after installing 13.10

Tags: system-installation, 13.10

I am new to Ubuntu and I just installed Ubuntu 12.04. Now my mouse no longer works. After hours of trying to fix it with one of you guys, we gave up. He said that the easiest way would be to switch to Ubuntu 13.10 because it had the support.

I put Ubuntu 13.10 on a USB, then when I clicked the option to erase everything and install Ubuntu it gives me a error message box:

> Header: ??? ???
>
> Body text: ??????

I have no idea how this happens. I am running Ubuntu 12.04, but with a trackpad and it's a pain.  What should I do?

---

Additional requested information:

I used Universal USB installer and UNetbootin to create my bootable USB.

Here is my GParted screenshot:
[image]

I would like to erase the previously installed Ubuntu and reinstall another version of Ubuntu on that partition because 12.04 is useless to me, but I will also add Windows dual boot.

Comment: which software did you used to create bootable usb?

Comment: Universal USB installer and  UNetbootin

Comment: did you got this error only during installation?

Comment: No right as i click erase all and install gives me error

Comment: boot from live usb and click on try ubuntu,is that a desktop screen opened or not?

Comment: Im posting this in the try ubuntu

Comment: upload gparted screenshot.

Comment: http://imgur.com/fyWnypt

Comment: did you want to erase previously installed ubuntu and reinstall another version of ubuntu on that partition?

Comment: Yes. since 12.04 is useless to me but i will also add windows duelboot

Answer (score 0):

- From the screenshot,it shows that your previously installed ubuntu was mounted,you cant erase a mounted partition and reinstall another version of ubuntu to it.
- So unmount the ext4 partition through gparted and then try to erase and reinstall ubuntu.
- To unmount a mounted partition,open gparted then rightclick on that partition you want to unmount and select the unmount option.Your partition will be unmounted successfully.

[image]

Comment: i did that.... i still get the same error. i have to go for the night

Comment: did you successfully unmounted the partition?If yes then,format that partition through gparted only.After that run the ubuntu installer.

Comment: The partition is unallocated now still giving me the error

Comment: create a new ext4 partition for ubuntu through gparted,run the ubuntu installer and then click on the option "something else" and choose the created ext4 partition for installing ubuntu.

Comment: No the thing is i can install 12.04 fine i also just used Os uninsataller i have no OS but its still giving me error